# If statement for tree list value?

Tags: c, gtk

How would I go about writing an if statement to check if "COL_NUMBER" is for example "3", this is the code that I got:

```
gtk_list_store_append (store, &iter);
  gtk_list_store_set (store, &iter,
                      COL_NUMBER, 3,
                      -1);

renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ();
  gtk_tree_view_insert_column_with_attributes (GTK_TREE_VIEW (view),
                                               0,      
                                               "Number",  
                                               renderer,
                                               "text", COL_NUMBER,
                                               NULL);
```

Comment: What do you want to know? How to write an if statement in [tag:c]?

Answer (score 0):

to get value from a treemodel, use gtk_tree_model_get ();